# What are short-term defenses against massive elegtromagnetic disruption?

Tags: warfare, weapon-mass-destruction, electricity, electromagnetism, lightning

A society comparable (in resources, technology, economics and politics) to present day Earth is gearing up for war. There is a weapon which causes massive, widespread electromagnetic disruption. Like an electromagnetic pulse, only worse because it is sustained for some time. As well as the EMP, this weapon involves the release of large quantities of protons and electrons which are a direct radiation hazard to humans.

It will cause high-voltage arcs along power lines, blow out large transformers, destroy thin wires and the microchips in modern cars, televisions, satellites, aeroplanes, etc, and basically wreck almost every undefended piece of electronics over an entire country.

This society-like-ours anticipates that this weapon will probably be deployed in a few days' time. **To what extent can they defend against the effects of this weapon?**

For example, would it be feasible to patch up the walls of a factory to make a Faraday cage to protect the machinery inside, or would that be ineffective? Would it be a good idea to leave your TV plugged-in to the Earth like (in British-style three-pin power systems)? Can anything be done about satellites at all? Is it a good idea to disconnect power stations from the national grid?

What can governments, businesses, and individuals effectively do to mitigate the damage?

Answer (score 1):

## Underground

The most economic solution would be to simply run all electronic equipment underground. The earth is a [good insulator](https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/1c3cif/if_dirt_is_an_insulator_how_is_it_able_to_act_as/c9db4l9/) (it is how we currently protect ourselves from *lightning*). It is also commonly available pretty much everywhere and building subterranean structures isn't very hard.